# Cascade drop down list box using java servlet, java script, jsp, database and Ajax. Withou using Jquery and Json

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, jsp, servlets

I did not have any hands on experience on Ajax. I want to use Ajax to create cascade drop down list box in my project. I have searched in net, i am able to get 
reference for using AJax with JSON and Jquery. But I want to use Ajax with Js alone. please find below the brief description of my issues and would be great
if I could get proper guidance here. Thanks in advance.
    1. I have to create two drop down list boxes 
    2. For the first drop down list box, I have hardcode values in JSP page itself.
    3. Based on the selection of the value in first drop down list box, the values need to get populated in the second drop down list box through database. 
    4. I want to achieve this through JSP,JS, Sevlet and Ajax. And not with JQuery and JSon. 
    Could any one help me with example code snippets?

I have tried to create request in my JS.I have given my servlet url , but it did not reach my servlet page. I have given  sysout in my servelet doget method for testing but 
it did not get printed in the console. Please find my code below and please guide me .

```
//my Js code
  function testDDL{
        var xhttp;

          if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {


            xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else {


            xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }

          xhttp.open("GET", "testServlet", true);
          xhttp.send();  

        }

    //my servlet code
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            System.out.println("I am in Test Servelet");                
        }
    //my web.xml config
     <servlet>
            <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>
                com.test.TestServlet
            </servlet-class>
     <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/testServlet/*</url-pattern>
       </servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because of my project implementation. I have formatted the url based on my project. Now its works fine. The code which I mentioned in the question will work fine.